# Email login error using python 3.6.2

Tags: python-3.x, web, gmail, python-requests

I am using python 3.6.2 . I am trying to check the validity of a gmail password using python. Here is my code-

```
import  os, sys, time, subprocess, collections, datetime, smtplib
from datetime import datetime

def passwordcheck(usr,psw):
    server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    try:
        server.login(usr,psw)
        ret = True
    except:
        ret = False
    server.quit()
    return ret

usr="myemail@gmail.com"
chk=passwordcheck(usr,"mypass")
print(chk)
```

But here the problem is whatever the password (right or wrong) it always returns False.How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Enable debug prints with `server.set_debuglevel(True)` and check for any errors.

Comment: Finally i got this. I had to turn on less secure apps for this from
[Turn on less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)
.BTW thank you. But is there any way to verify log in password without turn on this option?